# OLS Predict One Value Array

Tags: python, statsmodels

I try to just predict c, code below, I got error:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b=[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
model=sm.OLS(a,sm.add_constant(b)).fit()

c=[200]
c=sm.add_constant(c)
print (model.predict(c))
```

ValueError: shapes (1,1) and (2,) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)

If I put C=[2,200], I can successfully predict the numbers, however, when i just put one value i get error. Can I just predict one value?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48470628/getting-a-simple-predict-from-ols-something-different-from-6-to-8-of-statsmode add_constant currently doesn't support scalars, use c = [1, c] instead of add_constant.

Answer (score 0):

c should not be a vector, since it is scalar. You are trying to predict the corresponding Y value for c, the code should be:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b=[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
model=sm.OLS(a,sm.add_constant(b)).fit()

c=200
print (model.predict(c))
```

Comment: Thanks Emmet, the issue still exist. I think [1,c] works. As posted here"
 
duplicate of stackoverflow.com/questions/48470628/… add_constant currently doesn't support scalars, use c = [1, c] instead of add_constant. – user333700

Comment: what value do you expect for c=200? 400 or 100, or something else?